# Creating recursive static method to find product of prime numbers in array

Tags: java

The number 9 keeps returning true from my Prime method despite if(number % j == 0) returning true when 9/3 with no remainders but 0. Would someone like to help me with this? I'm also trying to not use for loops. It's for a homework assignment.

Edit: I've attempted the answer below but I still get the same issue using an if statement.

```
public class test {
    private static int product = 1;
    private static int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    private static boolean allowmultiply;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Product: " + findproduct(array, 0));
        }

    public static int findproduct(int[] list, int i) {
        int[] temp = list;
         if(i <= temp.length-1) {
            allowmultiply = Prime(temp[i], 2);
            if(allowmultiply != false) {
                product = product * temp[i];
            } 
            i++; 
            return findproduct(temp, i);
        }
        return product;
    }
    public static boolean Prime(int number, int j) {
        if(j <= number/j) {
            if(number % j == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            Prime(number, j+1);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

***NEW CODE: Thanks to WJS for the help!***

```
public class ProductPrimeNumber {
        private static int product = 1;
        private static boolean allowmultiply;
        private static int checker = 0;
        private static int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Product: " + findproduct(array, 0));
        }
    public static int findproduct(int[] list, int i) {
        int[] array = list;
        if(i <= array.length-1) {
            allowmultiply = isPrime(array[i], 2);
            if(allowmultiply != false) {
                product = product * array[i];
            } 
            checker = 0;
            i++;
            return findproduct(array , i);
        }
        return product;
    }
    public static boolean isPrime(int number, int i) {
        if(i < number) {
            if(number % i == 0 && i != number) {
                checker++;
            }
            isPrime(number, i+1);
        }
        if(checker > 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the code instead of images,

Comment: I coded in a system.out.println earlier to show me the numbers it was dividing. For 9, it showed that it did 9 % 3 = 0 but for some reason the if statement did not return false or something else.

Comment: Posted code does not compile.

Comment: the prime number , you want to find it via recursion only ?

Comment: `Prime` calls itself but ignores the return value; never a good sign.

Comment: I've edited it so it's less messy.

Comment: The "less messy" version is no longer recursive.

Comment: Sorry forgot to make it call itself when I brought it over to a separate pad.

Comment: You are using `product` as both a method and a variable; not illegal, but needlessly confusing.

Comment: Have any other ideas on what I might be doing wrong? Or maybe there is another way to find Prime Numbers without using Loops that doesn't involve if-statements?

Maybe there's another mistake I haven't noticed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.  Forget about primes for the moment as that is an entirely separate issue.  Consider the product of even numbers. The method is not as compact as it could be to aid clarity.

```
static Predicate<Integer> isEven = a -> a != 0 && a % 2 == 0;

int[] data = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
int prod = findProduct(data, 0);
System.out.println("prod = " + prod);
```

prints

```
prod = 3840
```

- define a lambda to test for even parity and > != 0. This isn't required but aids explanation.
- then call the method with the array and 0 to start.
- continue call the method until `i == v.length-1` (the last element).
- then `"unwind"` the recursive calls by first
  testing the even parity of `v[i]`
- if true, return `prod * v[i]`.
- otherwise, just return `prod`.

```
public static int findProduct(int[] v, int i) {
    int prod = 1;
    if (i < v.length-1) { 
       prod = findProduct(v, i+1);
    }
    if (isEven.test(v[i])) {
        return prod * v[i];
    }
    return prod;
}
```

The only difference between this and the prime solution is what your testing for.  So replace `isEven` with `isPrime`.  Then you just need to focus on your `isPrime` code.

The more compact version of `findProduct` is here.

- simply test for even parity
- multiply by the return product of either v[i] or 1
- when `i == i.length`, return `1` to start the unwinding process

```
public static int prodEven(int[] v, int i) {
    if (i < v.length) { 
        return (isEven.test(v[i]) ? v[i] : 1) * prodEven(v, i+1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! Gave me a new way to think about the problem. This is the new code as a result.

Comment: Since the boolean logic does not always work as I expect it to, I decided to use another way to track the inputs.

Comment: I tested my new changes from 1 to 1000.

Comment: I always reset the checker integer variable field before the end of a method or loop such that there is no conflict like before when I used only boolean coding like if statements and boolean itself to determine prime numbers.

Answer (score 0):

To do via recursion, you can start with a index ( say i that points to the starting of the array ).

**The base condition:**
when  i reaches the length of the array, then return 1 ;

**work to be done :**
in case the number is prime, multiply it with product and the return value from the calls of further functions and in case it is not, multiply the product with the return values from the calls of further functions.

```
public class PrimeProduct {
    static int product = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int list[] = { 3, 5, 9, 11 }; // 11*5*3
        int res = findProduct(list, 0);
        System.out.println(res);
    }

    public static int findProduct(int[] list, int i) {
        if (i == list.length) {
            return 1;
        }
        return isPrime(list[i], 2) ? product * list[i] * findProduct(list, i + 1) : product * findProduct(list, i + 1);

    }

    private static boolean isPrime(int num, int i) {
        if (i * i > num) {
            return true;
        }

        return (num % i != 0) ? isPrime(num, i + 1) : false;

    }

}
```

and the output is

```
165
```

Comment: Technically, `i` isn't a pointer; it is an *index*.

Comment: @ScottHunter yes, i agree  , have updated it to index, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Thanks, but when I try it without a for loop, I still get 1890 as my product.

Comment: @interestedinbeinginterested have updated my answer with recursion for IsPrime. please check